# SQL in migrationBuilder Incorrect syntax near the keyword

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

Usually, I can find answers here, but the error I'm getting is not specific enough for me to figure it out myself, beyond the fact that there must be a typo of some kind. I honestly don't know what's the typo though. I hope somebody can help.

I'm using .NET Core & EntityFramework (which is still new to me). I've created a couple of Migrations: 'initial' & 'populate'. 'populate' is an empty migration which I intended to use for seeding.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    foreach (var job in GetAllJobs().OrderBy(x => x.Id))
            migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO Jobs (Id, Code, Name, Role, Type, Group) " +
                                 "VALUES ('" + job.Id + "', '" + job.Code + "', '" + job.Name + "', '" + job.Role + "', '" + job.Type + "', '" + job.Group + "');");
}
```

For some reason, when running **dotnet ef database update** from command-line, it throws the aforementioned error: *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'"*, but I really don't see why.

[http://i.imgur.com/it5rP5P.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zknh.png)

I've tried omitting the semicolon at the end of the SQL statement, but that results in the same error. I really don't know what could possibly be wrong with the SQL statement :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    foreach (var job in GetAllJobs().OrderBy(x => x.Id))
            migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO Jobs (Id, Code, Name, Role, Type, [Group]) " +
                                 "VALUES ('" + job.Id + "', '" + job.Code + "', '" + job.Name + "', '" + job.Role + "', '" + job.Type + "', '" + job.Group + "');");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put bracket around identifiers, GROUP is a reserved word

Comment: Guess my inexperience with SQL queries shows :D . You learn something new every day. Thank you very much.